# spring boot 1.5.2 is not loading some classes throwing Unsatisfied dependency exception

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm using springBootVersion = '1.5.2.RELEASE', strangely it is giving following exceptions for the class PlainFileReader while execurting test JavaMainApplicationTests, it is happening only for some classes. I refactored the PlainFileReader into the package where other classes are working and added @componentScan in JavaMainApplicationTests annotations but strangely only some classes are not working, what could be the reason and how to trouble shoot it.

```
@Component
public class Graph<T> {

    @Autowired
    private PlainFileReader pjr;

    private Vertex<T> root;

    private ArrayList<Vertex<T>> vertices = new ArrayList<>();
```

.............

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(properties = "debug=true")
@ComponentScan("com.*")
public class JavaMainApplicationTests
```

..........

```
@Component
public class PlainFileReader {

    @Autowired
    private Parsers parsers;
```

.............

Error creating bean with name 'plainFileReader': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'parsers'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.PlainFileReader ' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Comment: Is Parsers class annotated with @Component or are you creating a bean for that?

Comment: yes, i'm creating the bean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem got solved but not sure the exact reason, while creating the spring boot project i created with com.test1 package and if I'm creating any classes within com.test1 are working but if I'm creating in com. those classes are not working.